# How to reset PhpStorm's theme to the default?

Tags: phpstorm

I recently installed the following theme (Material Theme UI): https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8006-material-theme-ui but now it has totally screwed my install and I can't understand the menus.

[image]

The editing section is fine but everything else is messed up.

How do I reset PhpStorm to the default?

Answer (score 3):

It is a known issue of [Material Theme UI](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8006-material-theme-ui) plugin: http://www.material-theme.com/docs/faq-troubleshooting/#feature-settings. You can follow the advice from the article or try disabling the plugin in **Settings | Plugins**.

Answer (score -1):

Another option would be a hard reset on the PhpStorm installation:

- uninstall phpStorm
- delete the settings, caches, plugins and logs files
  (*more details about these files (for Win, Linux and Mac) can be found [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519)*)

This worked for me.

**Be sure to make a list of all plugins you have installed or project(s) preferences you have configured in the global scope, because after the hard reset your IDE will be clean as a whistle (you will lose all your customisations).**